# Angular router events is not firing when navigating with routerLink

Tags: angular, router

I have a component where I need to check the current route url using code like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((val: any) => {
        if (val instanceof NavigationStart) {
        }
    });
}
```

For some reason when navigating to that component with `[routerLink]="['/person/edit', perosn.id]` the router event does not getting fired when clicking the link for a first time event if I refresing the page. 
Then if I click the link again the event getting fired.

Any thoughts why it is does not getting fired at first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngOnInit() is only called once after a component is instantiated, but not when the route changes.

You can inject the router and subscribe to it's events or params to get notified about route changes.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
ngOnInit() {
     this.route.params.subscribe(val: any) => {
        if (val instanceof NavigationStart) {
        }
    });
}
```